# web.xml list Servlets and Filters matched by a particular request

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, intellij-idea

I'd like to be able to determine which Servlets and Servlet-Filters match a particular request and the order in which they are called. In a simple web application this is trivial but in a complex application it can be very difficult to see exactly what will match just by viewing the web.xml file. It can be done by setting a breakpoint and viewing the stack but I'd like to be able to do it without having to fire up the application. I use IntelliJ and was hoping that it had such a feature, but I haven't been able to find it. I guess one could write a script to parse the web.xml file but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something exists already.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**MyEclipse** web.xml editor can fit some of your requirements http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webxmleditor/#ME

Edit: noticed later you are looking for IntelliJ